# How to find unique elements in a column of large csv file

Tags: java

Sample Input:-

```
A      B       C         D
1      10      a1        1a
2      20      b1        1b
3      10      c1        1c
4      20      d1        1d
5      30      e1        1e
```

Output:-

```
Unique elements in column B is/are 10,20,30
```

Comment: You can use [csvjdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/).  So you can use SQL on a csv file.

Comment: Do you know, how to read a file in java?

Comment: What is your concrete question? Is it about parsing the file, storing the results, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Set to store the data.

A Set is a Collection that contains no duplicates.

Comment: Agreed, just load each column into java, and then all load the values of that column into a set. It will then only contain the unique values.